# Testing a filter on a document on client-side

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Say I have a SON-document (typically fetched using a mongodb query, but not necessarily), and a query-filter expression (e.g. `{ 'x': {'$ne': 5} }`), is there a client-side way to test the document against the filter (using pymongo)?

Expected behavior:

```
satisfies({ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': {'$ne': 5} })
=> True
satisfies({ 'x': 5 }, { 'x': {'$ne': 5} })
=> False
```

Comment: can you please rephrase the question?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Gladly, what isn't clear?

Comment: May this is just me, but I actually can not understand what exactly do you want :-)

Comment: Completely off-topic but interesting still interesting question. If you ask about some existing solution I've never heard of one although it could be useful.

Comment: It's not python, but for JavaScript there is a lightweight MongoDB clone: http://dailyjs.com/2013/08/01/nedb/. You could extract some code out of [model.js](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/blob/master/lib/model.js)

Comment: Good call @hgoebl looks like 'function match (obj, query)' would do the trick. Maybe embed js in PY - https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/

Comment: @AlanSpencer thanks for the tip. I'd give it a shot.

Comment: @hgoebl thanks for the tip. I'd give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this interesting [mongomock](https://github.com/vmalloc/mongomock) project.

The [filter_applies()](https://github.com/vmalloc/mongomock/blob/master/mongomock/filtering.py) functions seems to be it.

```
def filter_applies(search_filter, document):
    """
    This function implements MongoDB's matching strategy over documents in the find()
    method and other related scenarios (like $elemMatch)
    """
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB's matcher algorithm is written in C++. You'd need at least a partial rewrite of the matcher in Python, which does not, to my knowledge, exist.