# pymongo find on list instead of db

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter, pymongo

Is there a way to use the `pymongo find` method on a list (or iterable) of dictionaries instead on performing the search on the database?

I have a list of dictionaries and I'd like to filter them using queries like in pymongo.

Is there any library that can do that?

Comment: related or even duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19950310/2096752

Comment: The link posted by @shx2 above does indeed answer my question. I have voted for this question to be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need an external library to accomplish that simple task. If i understand correctly you just need to filter a list of dictionaries based on some value.

```
def find(dict_list, key, value_list):
    return [dict for dict in dict_list if dict[key] in value_list]
```

You can then pass a list of dictionaries a key to match and values of that key that you want to search.

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. I need support for nested dicts and lists and also for special operators that would allow queries like {'price': {'$lt': 10}}. `filter_applies` from `mongomock.filtering` does just that.